# response is not defined when trying to modularize out express.get callback

Tags: express, get, response, webhooks

I have an express app initialized with end points similar to this (this is mounted on a /webhooks endpoint in my index.js, works with the current set up):

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function() {

    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get('/test', function(request, response) {
        //Do stuff
        response.send("success");
    });
    return app;
}
```

I have several different get and post endpoints, with a bit more in their bodies, so I wanted to make my initializer a bit more succinct to make what's going on here a bit more readable. So I tried to do this:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get('/test', test(request, response));
}

function test(request, response) {
    //Do stuff
    response.send("success");
}
```

This way, I'll be able to see my list of endpoints easily, and if I want to see what an individual one is actually doing I can go to that function. However, when I try to build my app, I get the error "response is not defined" at `app.get('/test, test(request, response));`

Am I missing something simple and obvious here, or does this set up not work? Am I stuck putting all of these function definitions within the `app.get()` calls?

======= EDIT =======

For clarity, I am using parse-server, and my index.js includes the following:

```
var Webhooks - require('./Webhooks.js');
app.use('/webhooks', Webhooks());
```

With the original question I asked, the webhooks work. I can successfully call `https://myapp.com/webhooks/test` and get a response. But, I have several webhooks, and want to keep this file clean. I first tried the implementation in my original question, but got `response is not defined` errors.

Then, I tried restructuring to the following:

index.js:

```
var WebhookController = require('./WebhookController.js');
app.use('/webhooks', WebhookController());
```

WebhookController.js:

```
const express = require('../node_modules/express');
const bodyParser = require('../node_modules/body-parser');
const request = require('../node_modules/request');
const Webhooks = require('./Webhooks.js');

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get('/test', Webhooks.test(request, response));

    return app;
}
```

Webhooks.js:

```
function test(request, response) {
    //Do stuff using request
    response.send("success");
}

module.exports = test;
```

However, Here when i try to access request it says "Can't access ____ of undefined", so request and response aren't even getting passed into Webhooks.test. If I do `app.get('/test', Webhooks.test(request, response);' I get the same "response is not defined" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will solve what you're looking for instead of helping you fixing the bug, which is a JavaScript issue: request and response has not been declared in the file and is undefined. The reason for it to work for routes is because its middleware in the express stack.

If you want to split out logic for different endpoints to different files you can do this easily like this:

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express')();

var UserController = require('./UserController');
app.use('/users', UserController());
```

**UserController.js**

Now, because we're adding this router to the /users endpoint, the addresses written here will be relative to this

```
var app = require('express');
var router = app.Router();

module.exports = function() {

  router.get('/', function(req, res) { /* get all users */ }      
  router.get('/:id', function(req, res) { /* specific user */ }

  return router;
}
```

Now, if you want to pass in arguments to the UserController, you'll add the arguments in app.js like

```
app.use('/users', UserController(argument));
```

And then use it in the controller

```
module.exports = function(argument) {
```

**OR**

**app.js**

```
var app = require('express')();

var UserController = require('./UserController');
app.get('/users', UserController.getAll);
```

**UserController.js**

```
module.exports = {
  getAll: function(req, res) { /* get all users */ },  
  get: function(req, res) { /* specific user */ }
}
```

The second approach is nice if you want to have all your routes listed in one file as a part of your documentation.

*PS*: If this is not what you're looking for, let me know and I'll delete the answer. a specially if I've misunderstood you

Comment: The first answer defeats the purpose of what I'm doing. This *is* already scoped out like that, basically this file I'm talking about is UserController.js and I'm trying to make that `module.exports function()` cleaner so I can tell what's all going on inside of it. without scrolling past several functions. The second answer is similar to something I just tried. I'll update my question with those details. I'll comment again when I've done so.

Comment: sounds good. clarification: you're not looking for something like this https://github.com/RobinGulbrandsen/react-blog/blob/master/server/src/routes.js ?

Comment: Just updted my question. That looks like what I'm trying to do but isn't working, though it is structured a bit differently than what you've got. I'll try refactoring a bit. Can I see your UserController file as well?

Comment: The entire project at github is open source, go nuts :) https://github.com/RobinGulbrandsen/react-blog

Comment: Is the main difference here the use of import vs require perhaps?

Comment: I've used import in other languages, but outside of my massive main.js file for parse-server and configuring index.js, I haven't really used node.js much, I've only required modules like Twilio

Comment: import is used with ES6, you're using ES5 :)

Comment: I see. It looks like you've properly answered the question I asked, so I've given you the correct answer. Thanks a ton. I'm running into an issue with my specific implementation, though, since some of my webhook handlers require calling Parse cloud functions. Any chance I could ask a couple questions in chat, since it's unrelated to the original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133920/discussion-between-jake-t-and-r-gulbrandsen).